# For loop, some data were missing when echoed/inserted to database

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I am having problem regarding the data entry with my radio buttons. I used for loop to insert the values of my radio buttons [1, 2, 3, 4 as their values BTW: this is for evaluation system]. The problem is, all the values where echoed/inserted correctly[such as: evaluatorsname, toevaluate'sname, id and areastorate] except the values of my radio buttons.

When I test the system or evaluate an employee, I graded the employee as follows: 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1 (five 4's, five 3's, five 2's and three 1's=18 rows). When I checked the database [dbname:tbl_semiresults], the database appeared :
[image: Screenshot of my database dataentry]

I think, the values jumped and those 'last' radiobtn values where omitted. Ive been thinking about this for days and i dont get it why some values of my radio buttons dont place themselves in the proper rows where I want them to be! HAHA HELP WITH THIS PLEASE ...

Any idea...

Here is my code: **Evaluation.php**

```
<form action="EvaluationPropSemi_.php" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr><br />
<th width="700px">AREAS TO RATE</th>
<th width="100px">1</th>
<th width="100px">2</th>
<th width="100px">3</th>
<th width="100px">4</th>
</tr>
<?php
$rates="select * from tbl_torateareas;";
$raters=mysqli_query($con,$rates);
$raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters);?>

<input type="text" name="employ" value="<?php echo $_POST['empname'];?>" />
<input type="text" name="activ" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>" />

<?php do{
?>

<tr>

<td><?php echo $raterows['torateareas'];?>
<input required="required" type="text" name="torates[]" value="<?php echo $raterows['torateareas'];?>" /></td>
<th><input required="required" type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $raterows['idtbl_torateareas'];?>]"  value="1" /></th>
<th><input required="required" type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $raterows['idtbl_torateareas'];?>]" value="2" /></th>
<th><input required="required" type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $raterows['idtbl_torateareas'];?>]" value="3"/></th>
<th><input required="required" type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $raterows['idtbl_torateareas'];?>]" value="4" /></th>
</tr>

<?php
}while($raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters)); ?>

</table>
</fieldset>
</tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="button1" name="push" />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's the EvaluationPropSemi_.php codes:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once("conn.php");
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);

if(isset($_POST['push'])){
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['torates']);$i++){
echo $_POST['activ'][$i];
echo $_POST['employ'][$i];
echo $_POST['torates'][$i];
echo $_POST['rad'][$i];

$emp=$_POST['employ'];
$act=$_POST['activ'];
$areas=$_POST['torates'][$i];
$score=$_POST['rad'][$i];
$insert="insert into tbl_semiresults (evaluator, toevaluate, areastorate, score) values ('$act','$emp','$areas','$score');";
$insertrs=mysqli_query($con,$insert);
$insertrows=mysqli_fetch_array($insertrs);

}
} 
?>
```

What's wrong with the codes? Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: You are using `rad[<?php echo $raterows['idtbl_torateareas'];?>]` in form and try to access it by `$_POST['rad'][$i]`. So, what is the value of $raterows['idtbl_torateareas']?

Comment: Sorry,Sir. Did access it the wrong way? How should it be ? :( BTW, values were entered in my database, it's just that-- the values jumped and some were omitted. Does accessing it by $_POST['rad'][$i] has something to do with it. Thanks Sir. I'm just starting to learn coding. @hellcode

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer to my question. HAHAHA, just to share to anyone who'll experience the same problem. HAHAHAHAHA!

There is nothing wrong with my codes and one thing I learn from this encounter: "If you think your codes are perfectly correct, then it is! The problem would surely be in the database :) That's it! I overlooked the idtbl_torateares. The reason why the 1st and 5th row doesn't display values of the radio buttons was, in my table tbl_torateareas, I didn't have 4 in my idtbl_torateares column plus in my loop, I started incrementing $i when equals (=) to 0, but in my table, idtbl_torateareas (ID) start with 1.

So that is why! :D